# Tikz: insert text/math (itemized) right of the figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to insert some text and math right of the following tikz picture: can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
\node (init) {};
\node [block] (A) {A};
\node [block, right=1.5cm of A] (B) {B};
\node [block, above=2cm of {$(A)!0.5!(B)$}] (C) {C};

\path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {$x^2-2x+5$} (B);
      \path [line] (C) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,left,align=center ] {$\int_1^2x^2 \text{dx}$} (A);
 \path [line] (C) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,right,align=center ] {$\lambda(t,s)$} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `columns` beamer environment. See chapter 12.7 of the `beamuserguide.pdf` document, version 3.36. (Now you see why I'd like to have a linkable, html version of all these nice LaTeX manuals...)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,calc}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=6em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4em
  },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.62\linewidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto]
            \node (init) {};
            \node [block] (A) {A};
            \node [block, right=1.5cm of A] (B) {B};
            \node [block, above=2cm of {$(A)!0.5!(B)$}] (C) {C};

            \path [line] (A) -- node [text width=2.5cm,midway,above,align=center ] {$x^2-2x+5$} (B);
            \path [line] (C) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,left,align=center ] {$\int_1^2x^2 \text{dx}$} (A);
            \path [line] (C) -- node [text width=1.5cm,midway,right,align=center ] {$\lambda(t,s)$} (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
        Text and 
        \[ y = f(x) \]
        formulas\dots
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

...and you will have probably to add spaces here and there to make it looks better. But you got the idea.

**Addendum** `\tikzstyle` is obsolete. A better definition with `\tikzset` has been provided.

Comment: I added a better definition for the styles, since `\tikzstyle` has long been deprecated.

Comment: @egreg, thanks. Thought about it but got lazy...

Answer (score 1):

Just small variation of Rmano answer (concerning picture). If you like to have vertical centering of columns, than omit option[T] in `\column`. My experiences show, that for the equation and text never enough big the column width, so I suggest that both columns have equal width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,quotes}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum width=5em,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=6ex
  },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Relations between A, B and C \dots}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2.5cm]
    \node [block] (A) {A};
    \node [block, right=of A] (B) {B};
    \node [block, above=2cm of {$(A)!0.5!(B)$}] (C) {C};

\draw[line] (A) edge["$x^2-2x+5$"] (B) 
            (C) edge["$\int_1^2x^2 \mathsf{d}x$" '] (A)
            (C) edge["{$\lambda(t,s)$}"] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item   $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
\item   considering
\[ c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \]
    more text \dots more text \dots more text \dots
\item   \dots
\item   \dots
\item   \dots
\end{itemize}

    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This MWE gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very helpful your answer as well! Best.

Comment: You are welcome. See my edits of answer. Happy TeXing!