# Some modification in TikZ: insert text/math right to the figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Following the question and answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313183/tikz-insert-text-math-itemized-right-of-the-figure)

I tried to modify the code for my needs. I was able to do so, although I still have a problem. My code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,quotes}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum width=5em,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=6ex
  },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Instrumental variables}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2.5cm]
    \node [block] (x) {$x$};
    \pause[2]
    \node [block, right=of x] (y) {$y$};
    \pause[3]
    \node [block, above=2cm of {$(x)!0.5!(y)$}] (z) {$z$};
\pause[4]
\draw[line] (z) edge ["instrument" '] (x) 
                (x) edge["instrumented" '] (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{.44\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item   $z$ is an instrument for $x$;\medskip
\item   $x$ is an instrumented regressor for $y$;\medskip
\item   The idea is that:\medskip
\begin{itemize}
\item $E\left( x|\varepsilon \right) \neq 0$\medskip
\item $E\left( z|\varepsilon \right) =0$\medskip
\item $E\left( z|y \right) = 0$\medskip 
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I like to show the graph sequentially. Only after I show the entire picture, I would like to show the text on the RHS. I tried to write `\pause[5]` before the beginning of the second column, but it does not work.

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,quotes}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum width=5em,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=6ex
  },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Instrumental variables}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2.5cm]
    \node [block] (x) {$x$};
\uncover<2->{
    \node [block, right=of x] (y) {$y$};
            }
\uncover<3->{
    \node [block, above=2cm of {$(x)!0.5!(y)$}] (z) {$z$};
            }
\uncover<4->{
    \draw[line] (z) edge ["instrument" '] (x)
                (x) edge["instrumented" '] (y);
            }
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{.44\linewidth}
\uncover<5->{
\begin{itemize}
\item   $z$ is an instrument for $x$;\medskip
\item   $x$ is an instrumented regressor for $y$;\medskip
\item   The idea is that:\medskip
\begin{itemize}
\item $E\left( x|\varepsilon \right) \neq 0$\medskip
\item $E\left( z|\varepsilon \right) =0$\medskip
\item $E\left( z|y \right) = 0$\medskip
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
    }
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Regarding to comments below, see if this rearrangement of MWE can help you in design of real transparencies ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,quotes}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    minimum width=17mm,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=9mm,
    font=\Large
  },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Instrumental variables}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 0.5cm]
\uncover<2->{
    \node [block] (z) {$z$};
            }
\uncover<3->{
    \node [block, below left=of z]  (x) {$y$};
    \draw[line] (z) edge ["instrument" '] (x);
            }
\uncover<4->{
    \node [block, below right=of z] (y) {$y$};
    \draw[line] (x) edge["instrumented" '] (y);
            }
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \hfill
    \begin{column}{.48\linewidth}
\uncover<5->{
\begin{itemize}
\item   $z$ is an instrument for $x$;\medskip
\item   $x$ is an instrumented regressor for $y$;\medskip
\item   The idea is that:\medskip
\begin{itemize}
\item $E\left( x|\varepsilon \right) \neq 0$\medskip
\item $E\left( z|\varepsilon \right) =0$\medskip
\item $E\left( z|y \right) = 0$\medskip
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
    }
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks a lot. I still do not like "uncover" (no specific reason for this), but admittedly it is very useful. Thank you again.

Comment: @Dario, in my answer I follow to your MWE, however from image I guessing, that first should be shown block Z, than X and Y ... In this case the construction of images should be different. Also probably would be interesting, that this frame will have on start empty "payload" and the first box will appear after clicking on it. This only require to add one `\uncover<2->{...}` to the first node and then increment all other ...

Comment: Yes you are right in both cases. Indeed this is my 'template' that I am going to change according to my needs. You are right in starting with the blanck page and that z should cone out before x. Thank you again for your suggestions!

Comment: See addendum to mine answer, may be of help ...

Comment: You can also use `uncover<+->{...}` all over, to avoid having to renumber them in case you add something in the middle...